# Upgrade Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series with more than 8GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, dell-inspiron

**I own a Dell Inspiron 15 3542.**
It has one SODIMM DDR3L RAM slot with an 8GB chip inside.
I read in the manual that only configurations of 2GB, 4GB, and 8GB are offered. Does this mean they just sell these laptops at a max of 8GBs of RAM (and that I can upgrade it), or does this mean that the motherboard only supports up to 8GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motherboard on your laptop only supports a maximum of 8GB of RAM. 
According to [Dell Support Forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19617772)

> The maximum memory supported on Dell Inspiron 3542/3543 is 8GB DDR3L
>   with clock speed of 1600 MHz.